# Z-порядок в JavaScript

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

Есть ли способ поменять z-порядок в JavaScript/GWT/CSS (необходимо, чтоб определенный, например div или картинка, элемент отображался поверх остальных)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[element].style.zIndex = 100;` - так меняется z-index. Остальное - особенности css (например, все элементы ранжируются по z-index только внутри родительского элемента).

Comment: z-index не помогает, пробовал.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index - может, статья поможет? А вообще, хорошо было бы увидеть пример вашей верстки.

Comment: Это будет проблематично. Пишу на GWT, кода очень много. Хотелось узнать общие принципы.

Comment: Общий принцип - такой же, как и в верстке. Только z-index меняется javascript'ом. Вручную задайте элементу z-index и посмотрите, что не так.

Comment: А возможно ли сделать элемент поверх всех остальных?

Comment: Можно, если озадачиться этим еще на момент верстки. Как вариант, можно закинуть элемент прямо в body и прописать ему position:absolute;z-index:1; (z-index должен быть больше z-index'ов других элементов). Наглядный пример - те же порнобаннеры на варезных сайтах. =)

Comment: Не забудьте, что z-index принемим только к тем элементам у которых position: absolute; в других случаях он просто не будет иметь никакого эффекта.

Comment: Можно также position выставить в fixed или relative. Там выше я ссылку дал на описание свойства.